# How do I merge two shapes in one during an animation?

Tags: after-effects, animation

I've these shapes:

[image]

---

[image]

The first one has three path within, my question is how do I merge these three dots into the big one during an animation?

I saw some tutorials about `reshape` but when I've tried it, it just appears the mask related to the first shape.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, there isn't a great automatic way of doing this in AE.

One technique is to make keyframes on your all shape paths, then paste the initial shapes into the path of the end shape after the required number of frames. The result often isn't good:

[image]

You're often better off manually moving all your bezier paths yourself.

PS:
There's a useful script called Masks to Shapes (rd_MasksToShapes.jsx) which was part of the [ReDefinery](http://redefinery.com/ae/rd_scripts/) Scripts bundle.  It seems to be offline now, but is [archived](http://web.archive.org/web/20190305110031/http://redefinery.com/ae/scripts/rd_scripts_20170108.zip) on the Internet Archive Wayback Machine, but it helps with switching between masks and shapes, but won't help with the morphing